# How to call confirm message from code behind in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hi I want to call a client side javascript confirm message from code behind in asp.net.

I want to use the true or false return value from the confirm message.

I'm doing like this, but this is not the correct way, please tell me how can I do the same.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myconfirm", "confirm('No Rule Type Ids found for This Rule.');", true);
```

Comment: I prefer to use typeof(MyPage) instead of GetType() saves the reflection (unless you're on a base page obviously)

Comment: I think its best that you add confirmation in html part    onclientclick="return confirm('Are you sure, you want to continue?');

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think This is what you want to achieve:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function Confirm() {
            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
            if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            } else {
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }
    </script>
```

.aspx code

```
<asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" OnClick = "OnConfirm" Text = "Raise Confirm" OnClientClick = "Confirm()"/>
```

C#

```
public void OnConfirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
    if (confirmValue == "Yes")
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked YES!')", true);
    }
    else
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked NO!')", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it is a god idea, but if you don't postback the page it doesn't work because appendChild command doesn't clear previous values.

Comment: Thanks, it works on my page with some modification. When working with asp's CustomValidator, in the .aspx code, use onserverclick="OnConfirm" onClick="Confirm();". The semicolon matters as run-time codes appended to onClick. There's no effect for onClientClick.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly writing confirm in the code behind. Write the name of javascript function.
Forexample,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myconfirm", "OpenConfirmDialog();", true);
```

In your javascript, write the function OpenConfirmDialog

```
<script>
function OpenConfirmDialog()
{
    if (confirm('No Rule Type Ids found for This Rule.'))
    {
       //True .. do something
    }
    else
    {
       //False .. do something
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: I want to use this true or false value in my C# code.

Comment: Yes. Since, confirm box is on the javascript side. You will have to send a request to server with either true or false. For example. You can request a webpage with query string like www.abc.com/default.aspx?result=true . On the server side you can get the value like Request.QueryString["result"].

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix client-side code with server-side code. The client side code (javascript) will not be sent to the client (browser) until the server-side code has completed.

You will need to stop processing and show the question to the user (maybe by a redirect to some other page), and then (on confirm) continue with your processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Write("<script language=javascript>");
                        Response.Write("if(confirm('El vehiculo no existe, Deseas crear el registro?')){window.location.href='IngresoVehiculos.aspx'}");
                        Response.Write("</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Open Message!');</script>");
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. "code behind" means the C# or VB code in the server, not the javascript in the client.

Answer (score -8):

You can do it without using Javascript function

Try

```
if (MessageBox.Show("confirm('No Rule Type Ids found for This Rule.')",
            "myconfirm",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // yes
    }
    else
    {
        //No
    }
```

Comment: @HansKesting Can you please explain why this won't work? It is working for me for a webproject (asp.net)

Comment: It might seem to work in a debug situation where everything runs locally. When it runs on a real server, that popup would appear on the server's console, not on the user's screen.