# open a confirmation dialog from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a button click event and in that after satisfying some condition , i should confirm dialog, if user clicks ok in that dialog, i want to proceed further in my code.

```
public void imgValidAdd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
     // Some Code
     if(A==b)
     {
        // Open Confirm dialog
        if(ok)
        {
           // Proceed
        }
     }
  }
  catch()
  {
  }
}
```

I have tried so many approaches, but nothing worked out

[How to call confirm message from code behind in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910796/how-to-call-confirm-message-from-code-behind-in-asp-net)

in the above link, i tried and implemented but the thing is ,if you don't postback the page, it doesn't work because appendChild command doesn't clear previous values

How do i work on this. help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

On aspx side

1) add a button for confirmed clicked

```
hidden button
<asp:Button ID="btnConfirmed" runat="server" OnClick="btnConfirmed_Clicked" style="display:none"/>
```

2) add a javascript function for confirm dialog

```
//Add a javascript openconfirmdialog() on aspx
function openconfirmdialog() {
    if(confirm('Confirm message')) {
        //fire hidden button click
        $('#<%=btnConfirmed.ClientID%>').click();
    } else {
        //else message
    }
}
```

On aspx.cs server side

3) fire javascript function from server side using Page.ClientScript

```
public void imgValidAdd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Some Code
        if(A==b)
        {
            // Open Confirm dialog
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "openconfirmjs", "<script>openconfirmdialog();</script>");
        }
    }
    catch()
    {
    }
}
```

4) Add a confirm button click method

```
public void btnConfirmed_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Proceed
}
```

Comment: Hi j4rey89,

Thanks for the help. Your solution is working too perfect as am expected. I was struggled for the past 30 hours to find out the solution for this.

One small change i made in your code as below
Instead of the 
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), 
    "openconfirmjs", "<script>openconfirmdialog();</script>");

I Used, 
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), 
    "openconfirmdialog", "<script>openconfirmdialog();</script>", false);

Comment: Yes, `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` would actually be better....Kindly check the green tick if my answer solved your question...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use window.confirm

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

```
if (window.confirm("Do you really want to ___?")) { 
  // do thing
} else {
  // don't do thing?
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work for my requirement, I want to check the confirmation dialog clicked yes/no in code behind(server side) as said like in my post example.