# ConfirmDialog() in JQuery on button click closing automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, confirm

I have a `ConfirmDialog()` function in `JQuery` being called by `asp:button` click event. It is working fine but when i click the `button`, `ConfirmDialog()` is called automatically closes dialog without click by the user. 
 I used:

```
function ConfirmDialog() {

                $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
    .html('<div><h4>' + 'Do you wanto to see previous data' + '?</h4></div>')
    .dialog({
        modal: true, title: 'Delete message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
        width: 'auto', resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            Yes: function () {
                //                $(obj).removeAttr('onclick');
                //                $(obj).parents('.Parent').remove();

                $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>Yes</i></h1>');
                $(this).dialog("close");
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            },
            No: function () {
                $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>No</i></h1>');
                $(this).dialog("close");
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
                document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
            });
```

I got that page refreshing is closing it. Then i tried with  $(document).ready() to stop the automatically closing but it is not working:

```
function ConfirmDialog() {
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
    .html('<div><h4>' + 'Do you wanto to see previous data' + '?</h4></div>')
    .dialog({
        modal: true, title: 'Delete message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
        width: 'auto', resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            Yes: function () {
                //                $(obj).removeAttr('onclick');
                //                $(obj).parents('.Parent').remove();

                $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>Yes</i></h1>');
                $(this).dialog("close");
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            },
            No: function () {
                $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>No</i></h1>');
                $(this).dialog("close");
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
                document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
            });
        };
```

And this is my button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnConfrm" runat="server" Text="View" ForeColor="Black" Width="80px"
                        CssClass="button" Height="30px" ValidationGroup="btn" OnClick="OnConfirm" OnClientClick="ConfirmDialog()"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call confirm message from code behind in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910796/how-to-call-confirm-message-from-code-behind-in-asp-net)

Comment: Yes I used `OnConfirm()` but the problem is before i click yes or no, the dialog being closed automatically.

Comment: No This is not a duplicate of that link, this is a different case.

Comment: My mistake.  Question is somewhat unclear.   Can you post your onConfirm() function code?  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Button syntax seems off.  And document.ready is not helping where you put it.

Can you post the onConfirm code (c#) ?

What happens if you try this ?

```
function ConfirmDialog() {

                $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
    .html('<div><h4>' + 'Do you wanto to see previous data' + '?</h4></div>')
    .dialog({
        modal: true, title: 'Delete message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
        width: 'auto', resizable: false,
        buttons: [{
            Yes: function () {
                //                $(obj).removeAttr('onclick');
                //                $(obj).parents('.Parent').remove();

                $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>Yes</i></h1>');
                $(this).dialog("close");
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            },
            No: function () {
                $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>No</i></h1>');
                $(this).dialog("close");
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
        }],
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
                document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);

        };
```

Comment: At best, this should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Don't worry, by the time I solve his problem this answer will be updated with more appropriate content.   This is just my initial way of contacting and gathering more information to help clarify the situation and hopefully lead to a solution.   I will, of course, delete this answer if someone else solves it first.

Comment: Answers shouldn’t be used to gather more information. That is what comments are for.

Comment: The scope of the problem and the amount of information exchange that will be required make the comments feature too limiting and cumbersome for this particular case.  Don't worry,  everything will be OK, I know what I'm doing.  I've been on SO a long long time, I just had to make this new account because I lost my login info.