# Confirmation like Yes/No after button click based on Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

Once the button clicked based on the condition it should show one pop up. Based on User Confirmation the code should execute.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                  (sender as Control),
                  this.GetType(),
                  "ToggleScript",
                  "Confirm();",
                  true);
                string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same question asked before.
This is the similar question I hope this would be helpful to you.
Please visit:
[How to call confirm message from code behind in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910796/how-to-call-confirm-message-from-code-behind-in-asp-net)